# Number formatting in Excel via xlwings from python (int to a comma seperated)

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm kind of new to programming.
My code runs perfectly. However, I would like to separate the output numbers from excel to "XXX,XXX" instead of "XXXXXX". Can you please advise?

Here is my function code:

```
def main():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wrd_input = input("Enter your word file name:")
    sht_input = input("Enter Panel sheet name:")
    oput_name = input("Enter output name for your document:")
    sht_panel = wb.sheets[sht_input]
    doc = DocxTemplate(wrd_input +'.docx')

    context = sht_panel.range("A2").options(dict, expand="table", numbers=int).value

    output_name = oput_name + '.docx'
    doc.render(context)
    doc.save(output_name)
```

Comment: Thanks, but still not working

Comment: Agreed, wrong format. Need more investigation.